# Differentiating user-provided and default optional parameters in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure, with one optional parameter, which defaults to `NULL`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_Test
@Param int = NULL
AS 
BEGIN     
    SELECT @Param
END
```

The problem now is: I want to see the difference between the user providing nothing (`EXEC P_Test`), and the user explicitly providing `NULL` (`EXEC P_Test @Param = NULL`);

Is there a way to detect this in T-SQL? Should the default value of `@Param` be something else?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal here? What happens if they supply NULL? What happens if they supply nothing? How much control do you have over what they supply? Can you not have a default and just make the supply of parameters be mandatory?

Comment: The stored procedure performs an update. Parameters represent a column within a table. When a parameter is set, I want to update the column with the provided value (even if it is `NULL`). When the parameter is not set, I don't want to update that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a `is_supplied(@param)` type construct in TSQL, you could go down the horrid route of a 'magic number' and default it to -1 to let you distinguish.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the magic numbering. The real stored procedure has a few more parameters of different types. I'd hate to default `VARCHAR` parameters to `THIS_IS_THE_DEFAULT_MAGIC`, it just screams bad practice :(

Comment: Surely there is no difference between `THIS_IS_THE_DEFAULT_MAGIC' and NULL both are values that are not normal values